# Is there a way to see profile view rankings of people in a specific company via the LinkedIn REST API?

Tags: rest, linkedin-api

I'm trying to make a Slack integration that posts the top 10 most viewed profiles where I work - is there a way to get this information from the Linkedin REST API or should I try and find a different way of getting this data? I couldn't see anything about profile view rankings in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to go ahead and answer this myself - No. LinkedIn recently got rid of their rankings on the main site (let alone the API) with their new UI change so this isn't even available through there any more.